# Finding Value, Related To Functional Equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

$f(x)$ is continuous for $\forall x \in R$ and $f(2x)-f(x)=x^{3}$

(1) $f(x)+f(-x)$ is constant ?
(2) $f(0)=0$ ?

I don't know how to use the continuity.
especially for $f(0)=0$ ?

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ seems to follow by plugging in?

Comment: I tried plugging in many times, but failed. Could you show the detail? please.

Comment: @gt6989b Nope. it will make $f(0)-f(0)=0$ that's true.

Comment: You are right, I misread the problem, sorry.

Comment: You cannot conclude $f(0)=0$, because if $f$ satisfies the equation, then $f+c$ also satisfies it, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. @exploringnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Instruction***

The key of the answer below is in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$. Think carefully what does it mean. After your finish reading my answer, look back at Inceptio's answer again and think
how the same approach will allow you to prove $f(x) + f(-x)$ is a constant without solving $f(x)$ explicitly.

***Answer***

Let $f(x)$ be any continuous solution for the functional equation:

$$f(2x) - f(x) = x^3$$

Let $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{x^3}{7}$, we have:

$$g(2x) - g(x) = f(2x) - f(x) - \frac{2^3-1}{7}x^3 = x^3 - x^3 = 0$$

Since $f(x)$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$, so does $g(x)$. For any $x \ne 0$,
we thus have:

$$\color{red}{g(x) = g(\frac{x}{2}) = g(\frac{x}{2^2}) = \ldots} = g(\frac{x}{2^n})
\implies \color{red}{g(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} g(\frac{x}{2^n})} = g(0)$$

From this, we can conclude $g(x)$ is a constant and hence $f(x)$ has the form:

$$f(x) = K + \frac{x^3}{7}$$ where $K$ is some constant. As a result, we have:

1. $f(x) + f(-x) = 2K$, a constant!
2. $f(0)  = K$, need not be zero!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where does $-\dfrac{x^{3}}{7}$ come?
How did you get $-\dfrac{x^{3}}{7}$ ?
I wonder.

Comment: First, the functional equation $f(2x) - f(x) = x^3$ is an inhomogeneous equation "linear" in $f$. Second, both arguments to $f$ are $x$ multiplied by a scalar factor. Third, the term in R.H.S is a simple power. All this together suggest one to look for functions of the form $A x^{\beta}$ as a particular solution of the functional equation. Substitute this into the function equation, it is then easy to see $A = \frac17$ and $\beta$ is the one we want.

Comment: Thanks. It's a special solution...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Simple definition as my guide says: If you can draw graph for the given function $f(x)$ without lifting your hand at all points, that's a continuous function. :)

Therefore, the given function has a graph which is continuous at every **real** point.

$f(2x)-f(x)=x^3 \implies f(x)=f(2x)-x^3$

$f(-2x)-f(-x)=-x^3 \implies f(-x)=x^3+f(-2x)$

Comment: so from here, $f(x) + f(-x) = f(2x) + f(-2x)$, why is that constant?

Comment: @gt6989b: That surely doesn't prove that as a constant, this is just a possible hint.:)

Comment: @gt6989b That hint proves function to be odd

Comment: For infinitely many real numbers (not all numbers), the values of $f(x)+f(-x)$ are equal. Can we tell it's constant? I don't know...
Could you tell me the detail? please.

Comment: @exploringnet odd would be only if $f(x)+f(-x)=0$ (this would follow from the second part, but not from here

Comment: Leave it. I told u that he has proved it. Read it again understand it how the proof work.